# Google Custom Search ALLOWALL

Tags: google-search, google-search-api, google-search-appliance

I have a problem with Google custom search identificator when I use   tag in html because google return X-Frame-Options for this identificator as SAMEORIGIN. For example:

Google custom search identificator 001234543187281414584:4j2px_wjqky
http://www.google.com/cse?q=widget&cx=001234543187281414584:4j2px_wjqky&cof=FORID:11&ie=ISO-8859-1&ad=w9&num=10#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=widget&gsc.page=1
Response headers is:  X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN

When I use this Google custom search identificator 008627251595762791990:hynttgqnjmq, then google return X-Frame-Options  as SAMEORIGIN and iframe is work fine. Where is the problem ? Where this options is choosen ?
For example:
http://www.google.com/cse?q=widget&cx=008627251595762791990:hynttgqnjmq&cof=FORID:11&ie=ISO-8859-1&ad=w9&num=10#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=widget&gsc.page=1
Response headers is:  X-Frame-Options   ALLOWALL

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Putting Google Custom Search in IFRAME is no longer supported

https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2641279?hl=en